# Upgrading Cucumber 4.5.x to v5.0.0

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I'm trying to upgrade an old test framework with Cucumber 4.5.x to a newer version. The project is a Maven, IntelliJ, Java, Selenium and Cucumber project.

But it seems that Cucumber either tries deliberately to mislead me, or that their documentation is incomprehensible to me.

First, I upgraded to version 5.0.0, reloaded the Maven dependencies and did a mvn clean install.

I immediately found out that

```
import io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario was gone.
```

After some manual searching, I found that the new path seemed to be

```
import io.cucumber.core.gherkin.Scenario;
```

Then I went to version 6.0.0, and here there doesn't seem to be any Scenario library anywhere.

Looking in the documentation, it seems to claim that Scenario is in

```
io.cucumber.java.Scenario
```

But that's not even right for version 4.5.x, so how the heck do I find the new path for the import?

UPDATE:

Before attempting the upgrade, I have the following in my plugins list:

```
io.cucumber:cucumber-core:4.5.2
io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:7.0.2
io.cucumber:cucumber-dependencies:1.1.14
io.cucumber:cucumber-datatable_1.1.14 
io.cucumber:cucumber.gherkin:5.1.0
io.cucumber:cucumber-tag-expressions:1.1.1
```

And in my pom.xml:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <selenium.version>4.3.0</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.version>4.5.2</cucumber.version>
    <junit5.version>5.5.1</junit5.version>
</properties>
```

Is the right way to change the version number in the pom.xml, and do a reload? Or should I replace the plugin with the newer version in the plugins list of the project (in IntelliJ)?

And should I upgrade any of the other cucumber-x plugins?

Alternative 1:

I change the version to 5.0.0 in the pom.xml file.

- The plugin versions for the other cucumber- plugins are updated automatically..

Build the project: OK
Run mvn clean install -> the following error occurs:

```
cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class Scenario
[ERROR]   location: package io.cucumber.core.api
```

Which, of course, is due to the change in the library.

But, when I try to replace the old

```
import io.cucumber.core.api.Scenario
```

with

```
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario
```

there is no match for .java.

I cannot see what else I can do? Which imports do I miss, and how do I add them besides updating the pom.xml and/or importing the new plugins?

Answer (score 5):

The jump from v4 to v5 is pretty big. A contributing factor to this was the introduction of the module system. You can read more about this and other changes in the [release notes folder](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/release-notes).

So for v5.x and up, assuming you are using `cucumber-java` then the right import is [`io.cucumber.java.Scenario`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v5.0.0/java/src/main/java/io/cucumber/java/Scenario.java). If you are using `cucumber-java8` then the right import is [`io.cucumber.java8.Scenario`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v5.0.0/java8/src/main/java/io/cucumber/java8/Scenario.java).

That neither import shows up suggests that you may not have upgraded all dependencies to the same version. You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to debug that.

Later versions also introduced a bill of materials to help you keep dependencies consistent with a single version number.

Comment: Thanks for cascading the information.

Comment: Ok. In my plugins list, before trying the upgrade, I have the following: io.cucumber:cucumber-core:4.5.2, io.cucumber:cucumber-expressions:7.0.2, io.cucumber:cucumber-dependencies:1.1.14, io.cucumber:cucumber-datatable_1.1.14, io.cucumber:cucumber.gherkin:5.1.0, io.cucumber:cucumber-tag-expressions:1.1.1. Should I just replace the cucumber-core plugin, or should I change the version in the pom.xml and reload? Do I need to upgrade/change any of the other plugins aside from cucumber-core?

Comment: Your dependency list looks quite broken. I would expect only `cucumber-java` and then maybe `cucumber-junit` or `cucumber-testng` depending on how your run your tests. If you use the CLI, then I would only expect `cucumber-java` as a dependency.

Comment: Not sure how to fix that?

Comment: You can use `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to work out which dependencies are transitive. Remove those from your dependency declaration. For what remains, try removing them one by one to see which ones are actually used. Then what remains should be upgraded in such a way that they all have the same version.